# Mui Textfield outlined variant is not rendering property after migrating from v4 to v5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have migrated the material-ui version from v4 to mui-v5. I have just installed all mui-v5 related libraries directly into project without uninstalling the v4 packages. I have started using the mui-v5 features and component in to seperate react components. Everything is working fine, But outlined textfield variant is not rendering property. the other variants like filled is working as expected. Same issue with Select component as well.

Below is image

[image]

Is there something wrong with migration?

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
                    <Select
                        id="demo-simple-select-label"
                        variant='outlined'
                        fullWidth
                    >
                        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
                <FormControl>
                    <TextField variant='outlined' /> // default variant
                </FormControl>
            </Grid>
```

Here is my package.json file

[image]

Comment: The migration doesn't support mixing the two versions. There are codemods for converting your v4 code to use v5. v4 styles will have side-effects on v5 components if you try to use both together.